# Return empty std::pair from function

Tags: c++, std-pair

Is it possible to return an empty pair from a function? Meaning, follow the rules of the function prototype, but do not have any elements in the pair (e.g. NULL). Understanding that a pair simply exists so I don't know if this is conceptually possible. I have a need to return a pair that is NULL or empty, if that makes any sense.

For example,

```
pair<int, int> MyClass::someFunction()
{

   // do something that means we need to return an empty pair
   return NULL; // <--- this does not work obviously
}
```

Unfortunately, boost is not a possibility for me.

Comment: pair is object... so what is "empty" pair?

Comment: @ForEveR: One which is constructed but contains nothing.

Comment: Again... pair is an object, it contains two ints, what do you mean that it contains *nothing*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: A `pair` is a `struct` so it can be empty per se.

Comment: *How* can a struct be *empty*? I am not sure you really understand the C++ object model if you believe that `struct`s can be empty...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It is true you can have an opaque struct. Plus, I don't find your comments constructive.

Comment: What would be your definition of an *opaque* struct? I am sorry you don't find the comment constructive, but I stand by it. I do believe that you should take the time to read a good book and understand the basics of the C++ object model.

Comment: `std::pair<T1,T2>` is defined to contain a `T1` and a `T2` instance. There is no clever stuff behind the scenes that would allow you to have anything smaller than `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are not sorry and I understand it completely. Please don't waste your time. I have already answered my question.

Comment: Why is boost not a possibility for you? Whatever reason you have, does it prevent you from borrowing the nearly-independent-of-the-rest-of-boost implementation of boost::optional and cleaning out the bits that aren't independent?

Comment: @abarnert: Because I do not control the baseline and I cannot install outside libraries.

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like you want to use  `return std::pair<int, int>();`. In other words, an "empty" pair contains two zeroes.

Comment: Boost::Optional is a pure-header library, so there are no outside libraries to install. And if you're talking about being even able to _build_ on arbitrary machines without requiring Boost, again, it's not that hard to extract Optional from the rest of Boost.

Comment: @abarnert: I can't use Boost.. not going to be allowed in baseline, ever. Not my call.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking an empty pair doesn't even make sense. Afterall a `pair` is per definition a container containing two objects.

You could however  make something like an empty pair using [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Then you would either use a `boost::optional<std::pair<...>>` giving you the option of returning either a pair or an empty state or use `std::pair<boost::optional<...>, boost::optional<...>>` for a pair where either object could be empty.

Comment: Don`t forget about space between ">>". I mean boost::optional<std::pair<...> >

Answer (score 4):

You can returns pointer... Or use `boost::optional<T>`. Optional will be better...

```
boost::optional<std::pair<int, int> > MyClass::someFunction()
{
    return boost::optional<std::pair<int, int> >();
}

void f(const MyClass& f)
{
    boost::optional<std::pair<int, int> > ret = f.someFunction();
    if (!ret) // empty
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your questions is easily explained by considering the way the C++ compiler generates code in this case.

The `std::pair<int, int>` is returned-by-value.

Since `MyClass::someFunction()` is returning an object by value, the sequence of events is as follows:

- The calling function reserves space on the stack for a `std::pair<int, int>`
- The `MyClass::someFunction()` is called
- The right hand side of the return statement is a assignment to the location reserved on the stack earlier.  There is an implicit construction of a `std::pair<int, int>` taking place.

Thus returning a NULL pointer is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't take much to create your own "optional pair" (similar to `boost::optional<std::pair<…>>`, but with a different interface), e.g.:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct OptPair : std::pair<T1, T2>
{
  typedef std::pair<T1, T2> base_t;
  bool contains;
  OptPair() : contains(true) {}
  explicit OptPair(bool x) : contains(x) {}
  OptPair(const T1& x, const T2& y) : base_t(x, y), contains(true) {}
  template <class U, class V>
  OptPair(const std::pair<U,V> &p) : base_t(p), contains(true) {}
  template <class U, class V> OptPair(const OptPair<U,V> &p) : base_t(p), contains(p.contains) {}
  // No need to define operator=, as the default will construct an OptPair<T1, T2>
  // if necessary, then copy members into *this.
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
OptPair<T1, T2> makeOptPair() { return OptPair<T1, T2>(); }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
OptPair<T1, T2> makeOptPair(const T1 &x, const T2 &y) {
  OptPair<T1, T2> p(true);
  p.first = x;
  p.second = y;
  return p;
}

template <typename OS, typename T1, typename T2>
OS &operator<<(OS &os, const OptPair<T1, T2>& p) {
  os << "<OptPair: ";
  if (p.contains) os << p.first << ", " << p.second;
  else os << "empty";
  os << ">";
  return os;
}
```

Then you can use it just like std::pair (and even use it interchangeably with std::pair, assigning values back and forth), but with the added ability to pass an "empty" value back like this:

```
OptPair<int, int> someFunction()
{
   ...
   return OptPair<int, int>(false); 
}
```

You have to make sure to check the result before using it, like this:

```
void doStuffWithPair(std::pair<int, int>);
void doStuffWithEmpty();
...
OptPair<int, int> ret = someFunction();
if (ret.contains) doStuffWithPair(ret);
else doStuffWithEmpty();
```

Comment: @abarnert That's just an idea how it can be resolved. if you can improve the answer please do it so.

Comment: @abarnert I edited the code, review it and feel free this time to edit it :P

Comment: OK, I think I've coded up what you intended. Let me know if it's right.

Comment: The big problem with this solution is that it's easy to accidentally forget to check contains, and then use garbage first and second values. With other solutions like a pointer, boost::optional, etc., you'll usually get a crash (or, even better, an exception or a compiler error). You could probably handle this by, e.g., embedding pair instead of inheriting, and adding an `operator std::pair<T1, T1> &` that throws if `!contains`.

Comment: The smaller problem with this solution is that it makes the structure 16 (or 12 or 9) bytes instead of 8, and repeated checks to contains may be a performance hit. This probably isn't worth worrying about at all. If it is, returning a temporary and immediately copying it to `std::pair` will make sure you do the check exactly once and don't keep any extra bytes around.

Answer (score 1):

A pair, by definition, has 2 elements. It cannot have none.

You need something like `boost::optional<std::pair<T1,T2>>`. Then you can choose to have a pair or not. You can find documentation for boost::optional [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).